# Clarifications for suspensions in chat

Tags: support, chat, account-suspension, chat-flags

Just now, I was suspended from MSE chat. I was told not to bring up certain topics and was silenced for 30 seconds, so I accepted this and refrained from discussing the topic. Shortly after that as the conversation moved on, I was suspended for 3 hours without warning despite not bringing up any of the past topics. How do I find out what rules have been violated so I can respect them in the future?

Was this the result of some previous message being flagged and the flag only now being reviewed?

Comment: Now the suspension is for 1 year.

Comment: The escalation of suspension from three hours to an entire year is suspect. Those with moderation tools at their disposal are also fallible and sometimes require a "cool-down" period.

Comment: Did the suspension jump to a year because OP asked on Meta?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Either because of that, or because I replied to the answer saying that I found some of the accusations offensive. Those are the last two interactions I had on MSE between the chat suspension and the year-long site suspension, so it had to have been one of those.

Answer (score 3):

...no, it was not due to a flag being handled, and you're well aware of that. This was a manual suspension, which means there was a reason behind it.

---

So... there's a lot of context at play here, much more than what you've put into your post.

First of all, you have a long history of pushing people's buttons and trolling folks in chat. You are perfectly aware of that - heck, you even said something to that effect during the conversation that led to this post.

Second, there was the atmosphere of the room at the time. I'm fairly sure I had made it *very clear* that if you (general you) weren't trying to be constructive, then I had no patience for you. Things were obviously slightly tense.

You came in and started rehashing the discussion, well aware of the tense state of the room. This led to at least two arguments between you and one other user.

Now, I don't like holding grudges. If someone has sincerely gotten over something they used to do, that's great! But when someone has shown a repeated pattern of behavior with no signs of stopping... that's context that is relevant in managing a situation.
In light of your history, and the fact that things were starting to devolve between you and another user, I put the room in timeout for two minutes.

> This room was placed in timeout for 2 minutes; This isn't going anywhere constructive. Let's take two minutes to cool off.

Immediately after that timeout wore off, the conversation resumed with no change. People obviously hadn't taken my hint that the conversation wasn't heading somewhere positive.

I didn't suspend you. I can't; I'm not a moderator here on MSE. But as a Tavern RO, I can understand the decision fairly well. You have a long history of intentionally pushing people's buttons. Today was a bad day to be pushing people's buttons, and you got slapped by a trout when it was felt that you were simply doing exactly that.

If you don't want people to think that you're intentionally pushing people's buttons when you're not, then stop intentionally pushing people's buttons in the first place. Because your history of behavior does actually affect the level of patience people have for putting up with you, and the fact that you've received so many warnings over time means you're less likely to get a warning now and more likely to simply receive a kick.

And finally, three hours is nothing. It's almost the smallest possible manual suspension a moderator can issue. It's a slap on the wrist; nothing more. Let it serve as a warning for the future.

Comment: _and you're well aware of that._ I don't think such accusations are helpful.

Comment: @TheforestofReinstateMonica - The message that you see when you enter chat clearly states that you've been temporarily suspended by a moderator. If it had been due to a flag, it would have said "for posting inappropriate content" with a link. I'm relatively sure you have experience with both types.

Comment: You're making accusations again and **I don't appreciate that.** Flags can be manually reviewed by moderators, no? I knew that it was not an _automatic_ flag because it was not a 30 minute suspension. I had assumed that it was a manual flag that a moderator got to and only then acted on. I can see that you're assuming bad faith because I have a history of pushing buttons, and I admit that, but that does not excuse unfriendly behavior on your part.

Comment: Do you see why I find this answer offensive? It feels to me like you're calling me a liar and then telling me, because I have a history of pushing buttons, that it doesn't matter if the suspension was fair or not.

Comment: *three hours is nothing* -- a year is another story altogether.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to explain what __content__ led to the suspension, but rather, explains the context (accusations of a past history, a _feeling_ of the room being "tense")

Comment: This whole post to me reads more like "We don't like you, that's why we banned you", than giving any explanation as to *why* he was suspended. And the fact that his Meta account has *also* been suspended only reinforces that.

Comment: @MechMK1 The meta account of him or her has been suspended for different reasons by different people, I guess. The meta suspension was because he or she dared to ask why Robert Harvey was suspended, I think, but I don't remember or know all the details anymore. This incident here might be not directly related.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like things have escalated to another level.

Comment: “Immediately after that timeout wore off, the conversation resumed with no change.“ - this is a flat out contradiction of what the OP says in the question.